# I there any way to filter the data in table when clicked one part of section pie chart? laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i had implement the click event for the chart and it can filter the data in the table. But now i face the problem of the data does not return all the data in the table when click outside the chart are.How can make it return all the data when click outside the area chart? Thank you. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
<script>
import VueApexCharts from "vue-apexcharts";
import faker from "faker";
export default {
  components: {
    VueApexCharts,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Lists: [],
      selectedData:{},
      search1:'',
      clicked:'',
      clicked1:'',
       isLoading1:true,
      currentPage: 1,
      series: [300, 200, 49, 100,290, 228, 119, 55],
      chartOptions: {
        colors: ['#7961F9', '#FF9F43', '#196EB0', '#2EAB56','#df87f2','#057FF2', '#14DA6E','#FF5500'],
        legend: {
          fontSize: "14px",
          position: "top",
        },
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              minAngleToShowLabel: 0,
              distributed: false,
              style: {
                colors: ['#111'],
              },
              background: {
                enabled: true,
                foreColor: '#fff',
                borderWidth: 0,
              }
            },
        chart: {
          width: 500,
    type: 'pie',
          events: {
            legendClick: (chartContext, seriesIndex,w, config) => {
              this.clicked = w.config.labels[seriesIndex];
              console.log(this.clicked);
              console.log(seriesIndex);
            },
            dataPointSelection: (event,chartContext,config) => {
            this.clicked1 = config.w.config.labels[config.dataPointIndex];
            console.log(this.clicked1);
            },
         },
        },
        labels: ['Private', 'Local','Dental', 'Government','Cyber Security', 'Health', 'Foreign','Medical'],
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            options: {
              legend: {
                position: "bottom",
                fontSize: "12px",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
        }
      },
    created() {
    this.getData();
      this.getData1();
  },
  computed:{
    filterLists(){
      let list =  this.Lists;
      if(this.search1 !=''){
      list =  list.filter((tr)=>{
        return tr.agency.toUpperCase().includes(this.search1.toUpperCase())
      });
    }
    if (this.clicked !=''&& this.clicked){
        list =  list.filter((tr)=>{
         return tr.projectCategory.toUpperCase().includes(this.clicked.toUpperCase())
      });
      }
        if (this.clicked1 !=''&& this.clicked1){
        list =  list.filter((tr)=>{
         return tr.projectCategory.toUpperCase().includes(this.clicked1.toUpperCase())
      });
      }
    return list;
    },
},

 methods: {
    next(page) {},
    getData1() {
        this.isLoading1 = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.randInt(8, 4); i++) {
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        let projectCategory = this.rotate([
          'Private', 'Local','Dental', 'Government','Cyber Security', 'Health', 'Foreign','Medical'
        ]);
 
        this.Lists.push({
          projectCategory:projectCategory,
          project_name: faker.company.catchPhrase(),
          agency: faker.company.companyName(),
          logo: faker.image.abstract(),
        });
      
           }
      this.maxPage = 2;
      this.isLoading1 = false;
    },

       next1(page) {
      if (page == -2) {
        this.currentPage = 1;
      } else if (page == -3) {
        this.currentPage = this.maxPage;
      } else {
        if (
          this.currentPage + page < 1 ||
          this.currentPage + page > this.maxPage
        ) {
          return;
        }
        this.currentPage += page;
      }

      this.showLoader("#card-list");
       this.Lists = [];
      this.isLoading1 = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.closeLoader("#card-list");
        this.getData1();
      }, 1500);
    },
   
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
<style>
#card > header{
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  background-color: #2E3839;
}

#card{
--tw-bg-opacity: 1;
background-color: rgba(249, 250, 251, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.con-img.vs-avatar--con-img img {
  object-fit: cover !important;
}

.apexcharts-toolbar {
  position:absolute; 
  margin-right:12px;
}
vs-button.btn:hover{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="mb-base">
    <div class="vx-row mb-base">
    <div class="vx-col 2/3 w-full mb-base">
        <vs-card
          id="card"
          class="vs-con-loading__container h-full"
        > 
        <template slot="header">
          <div class="flex">
            <div>
              <img
                src=""
                alt="Info"
                class="h-12 inline-block mr-4 object-scale-down"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col justify-center w-full text-start">
              <h3 class="text-white">Source of Fund</h3>
              <span class="text-sm text-white">Based on Total Billed (Yearly)</span>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
          <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-2">
            <div class="lg:w-1/3 w-full">
          <vue-apex-charts
          type="donut"
          :options="chartOptions"
          :series="series"
          width="100%"
          class="items-center justify-center flex mt-16 content-center"
         
          />
            </div>
            <div class="lg:w-2/3 w-full lg:pl-6 pl-0 mt-6">
              <div class="flex justify-end items-end">
                <vx-input-group class="mb-base lg:w-1/2 w-full">
                  <template slot="append">
                     <div class="append-text btn-addon">
                    <vs-button color="#A9A9A9"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></vs-button>
                  </div>
                  </template>
                  <vs-input
                    v-model="search1"
                    placeholder="Project Code or name"
                  />
                </vx-input-group>
              </div>
              <div id="card-list"> 
              <vs-list v-if="!isLoading1">
                <vs-list-item
                  v-for="(tr, index) in filtertLists"
                  :key="index"
                  class="hover:shadow cursor-pointer text-base mb-4"
                >
                  <template slot="title">
                   <div
                    class="flex flex-col ml-2 cursor-pointer"
                  >
                   
                      <div class="font-bold">{{ tr.project_name }}</div>
                      <div>{{ tr.agency }}</div>
                    </div>
                  </template>

                  <template slot="avatar">
                    <vs-avatar :src="tr.logo"></vs-avatar>
                  </template>
                  {{ tr.projectCategory }}
                </vs-list-item>
                 <div v-if="!filterLists.length" class="flex">
            <div class="items-center justify-center text-lg font-bold">No record...</div>
          </div>
          </vs-list>
              <div v-else class="flex">
            <div class="items-center justify-center">Fetching data...</div>
           </div>
          </div>
              <div class="flex justify-end gap-4">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center text-sm">
                  Page {{ currentPage }} of
                  {{ maxPage }}
                </div>
                <div>
                  <vs-button
                    type="filled"
                    color=" rgba(243, 244, 246)"
                    class="w-10 mr-2 rounded-md bg-gray-400 text-black btn hover:text-black"
                    @click="next1(-1)"
                  >
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                  </vs-button>
                  <vs-button
                    type="filled"
                    color=" rgba(243, 244, 246)"
                    class="w-10 mr-2 rounded-md bg-gray-400 text-black btn"
                    @click="next1(1)"
                  >
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                  </vs-button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </vs-card>
      </div>
    
      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am working with laravel vue pie chart. is there any way to filter the data in the table when click the element of pie chart. For example, when clicked the section pie chart, the table will be filter and display the the data in the table under that section..Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to point directly to a solution as you have given so little detail. I will still try to explain the logic. For this process, you will get an input from the screen working with Vue.js and you will manipulate a data displayed on Vue.js.

So first; you need to know which part of your pie chart clicked on. I assume the pie chart you are using on your project have some events which triggered when you interact with charts. You will listen that event and catch the value of clicked item.

Now you have the value of clicked item and you need to `filter` your results by that.

To accomplish that you can use Vue.js Computed Properties and Watchers  :https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Lets say you have your data on your Vue.js application:

```
data () {
  return {
    clickedItem: null,
    itemsOnTable: [ ... ]
  }
}
```

You have all your table content in `itemsOnTable` and selected item's data in `clickedItem`

You can use `computed` to filter your data:

```
data () {
  return {
    clickedItem: null,
    itemsOnTable: [ ... ]
  }
},
computed: {
  //  filter itemsOnTable if clickedItem have any value
  filteredItems: function () {
    if(this.clickedItem==null) return this.itemsOnTable;
    return this.itemsOnTable.filter(item => item.column = this.clickedItem);
  }
}
```

Now in your Vue.js component you can directly use `filteredItems` for your table elements `v-for`

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="items in filteredItems">
        <td>{{ item.column }}</td>
        <!-- other columns -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

This examples explains basics of interactions and computed properties and aims to help you to understand basics.

Comment: Hi, i had implement the click event for the chart and it can filter the data in the table. The table originally return all the data.  For example, the table will only display the data that under that category when one of section of chart or legend clicked. But the table does not display to the original data when clicked outside of area chart or outside the legend click. But now i face the problem of the data does not return all the data in the table when click outside the chart are.How can make it return all the data when click outside the area chart? Thank you. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: To change it back to all data you need to set `this. clickedItem` to `null` again.

Comment: i try but it does not return